# Catching kendo UI grid filter changed event to save/load options

Tags: javascript, filter, dom-events, kendo-grid

Is there a way to catch the filter-changed event to store/show the filter options?

I would use it to initialize grid filters (as they were) after site-reload.

Comment: Check out kendo grid [persist state](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe a filter event:

```
filter: function(e) {      
  if (e.filter != null) {
        //do something with filter e.g save to local storage or somewhere
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Przemysław,

Yes I use it as following to store / load the filters from session storage (typescript). Filters should be read by dataBound (or change) event - callback. Later after a site reload the data source should be configured with saved filters - as you have already mentionated.

```
// Save filters to storage
const grid = new kendo.ui.Grid (
    ...,
    dataBound: (e) => {
        const filters: kendo.data.DataSourceFilters = this.kendoGrid.dataSource.filter();
        if (filters) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("kendo-filters", kendo.stringify(currentFilters));
        }
    },
    ...

// Set kendo filters from storage
const o = sessionStorage.getItem("kendo-filters"); 
const filters: any  = o ? JSON.parse(o) : {};
public createDataSourceOData() : kendo.data.DataSource {
    ...,
    filter: filters || {},
    ...,
}
```